# WIFI constantly disconnects when watching online stream video on my mbp

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos

My mac is Macbook Pro (mid2014), OSX 10.11.3 (15D21).
It disconnects literally every one minutes when I am watching stream on douyutv.com (Chinese version of  Twitch).
My other devices(smartphone, pad, pc) works all right. I did an experience that watch stream on all my devices, only mac disconnected.

Is it a bug or just something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: I tried to watch twitch just now, wifi disconnected as well.

Comment: Could you check your logs? Ie start the "Console.app", search for "arpt" (airport) and see if you see something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this quick-n-dirty solution.

### Reset the WiFi

1. From toolbar -> `Go` -> `Go To Folder`
2. Paste this Address `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`
3. Locate and delete these files

   - `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
   - `com.apple.network.identification.plist`
   - `com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist`
   - `NetworkInterfaces.plist`
   - `preferences.plist`
4. Restart your Macbook

You can read further for WiFi issues and solutions [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried all solutions on that webpage. Don't work. This issue only happens when I watching stream. Surfing web, playing online games are not affected.